# Where does the look of wpf come from?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just read the book on [WPF from Thomas Claudius Huber](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/wpf/). He stated, that all WPF controls are "lookless". They just get their look (and visual tree) from their `ControlTemplate`. That raises one question: *Where does the look of WPF come from?*

I mean: the `Button` has a `ControlTemplate` with some `Border`s and a `ContentPresenter`. Where do these two (`Border` and `ContentPresenter`) get their look from?

I already googled and found, that `Border` is a `Decorator` and sets its look in the `OnRender`-Method.

Is that the bottom line? Do all other elements which don't have a ControlTemplate define their look in the `OnRender`-Method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: *Yes*. All visual elements that are not Controls and have a "look", define said look in their `UIElement.OnRender` method override.

Long answer: **Controls** don't use the `OnRender` method to define their looks. Instead, their "looks" are defined in Styles and Templates. When no Style or Template is defined explicitly in an application, WPF Controls simply use their default Styles and Templates from the current system **Theme** (for more info on Themes, check [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa358533(v=vs.90).aspx)).

Let's just say that the Framework has its own Resource Dictionaries with default Styles for all built-in controls. For instance, here is the default ControlTemplate of the ComboBox: [ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/Library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx)

That being said, there are several visual components that have their looks defined through code, usually through the `OnRender` override. They're not Controls; they're **Decorators**, **Shapes** and things like that. Things that do have a "look": Border, Rectangle, etc. But in the end, all Controls have look thanks to these elements because all ControlTemplates are made up of either these elements, or other Controls.

**TextBlock**, as **Run**, **FlowDocument** and other similar elements, are special elements created specifically for text renderization. They fall into a similar category than Shapes or Decorators, except they specialize on text rather than graphics. TextBlock, for instance, is not a Control, and defines its look on its `OnRender` method. Label, on the other hand, IS a Control; but if you check its Template, you'll see it ends up using a TextBlock to show the text.

There are other elements (like **ContentPresenter**, **ItemsPresenter**) that have no look whatsoever, not implicit, not by default, not by Styles or Templates. These are logic elements, that define the structure of the view. ContentPresenter, for instance, grabs the `Content` and `ContentTemplate` properties of a ContentControl, and makes sure that said Template is correctly rendered and bound to said data, so to speak. But they have no visual representation of their own.

Oh, and I almost forgot about **Panels**. Panels are not Controls, either, and they do have a look of their own. But similarly to Presenters, they're also logic elements that define how the other visual elements are visualized. More specifically, their layout.

Comment: This is true. In fact, you can demonstrate this by setting any control's `OverridesDefaultStyle` property to `true`. The control will visually disappear, as it now has no default "look" or "style" applied.

Comment: Though, re-reading the OP, he's asking about "primitive" controls like Border, etc... I'll edit my answer to talk about those.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, that gets my point. I was speaking about all the "primitive" elements like Border. I also wonder where the `TextBlock` gets its look from. How does it get the Text on the screen?

Comment: `TextBlock`, as `Run`, `FlowDocument` and other similar elements, are special elements created specifically for text renderization. They fall into a similar category than Shapes or Decorators, except they specialize on text rather than graphics. Also, `TextBlock` is not a Control. `Label` is a Control, but if you check its Template, you'll see it uses a `TextBlock` to show the text, in the end :P

Comment: And the question was: How does the `TextBlock` get the Text on the screen? Does it do that in the `OnRender`-Method? Does it all come down to this method?

Comment: Looking at its source code (http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock@cs/1/TextBlock@cs), I'd say yes: the `OnRender` method does the visual work in this case, too.

Comment: So actually the answer to the question "Does everything on the screen come from the `OnRender`-method?" should be "yes". Or are there other ways?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, `OnRender` is the only way for all UIElements, which include Controls, Shapes, Decorators, Panels, TextBlock et al, etc.

Comment: Not-so-short answer: UIElement inherits from Visual, which is the actual responsible for rendering, and there are a handful of classes that inherit from Visual as well and don't use `OnRender`... But they're not really conventional in WPF, at all. Also, nothing's stopping you from creating your own class that inherits from FrameworkElement or UIElement and create some "look" through the `OnLoad` method, instead of the `OnRender`... But if you manage to get that working, expect some weird visual glitches.

Comment: So in your answer you said that "Nope", and in the comment before last you said "yes". As long as there is this discrepancy, I can't accept your answer. Maybe it would be helpfull, if you add your comment to your answer.

Comment: Humph, I guess you're right. Even if Controls _are_ lookless, their look comes, in the end, from non-Controls which indeed define their looks in the `OnRender` method. Editing accordingly!

Comment: Done. I'd say it is a good summary about WPF visual elements.